# CMFCButton::SetImage - Bitmaps won't show

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm trying to load bitmaps for my buttons with the function `SetImage` from the `CMFCButton`. I don't get any error or something, just a plain button. I'm doing the same thing with `icons` and it works, but I need it to load `bitmap` too. I need to `LoadImage` from a path and not from the resources.

Here's my code :

```
iconResource = path + m_type + _T("U") + extension; //i.e : C:\test\earthU.bmp
HANDLE hIcon =  ::LoadImage(nullptr, iconResource, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
//same thing for Hot and Disable bitmap
```

and the call for the `SetImage` function :

```
SetImage((HBITMAP)hIcon, 0, (HBITMAP)hIconHot, 0 , (HBITMAP)hIconDis);
```

Comment: You may or may not get errors, but you do not know, because you ignore checking for errors. `LoadImage` reports errors by returning `NULL`. With the code snippet provided, we also cannot see, whether `iconResource` holds the correct value. What `operator+` does depends on the types of `path` and `m_type`.

Comment: Have you checked that `LoadImage` succeeds? If it doesn't, have you checked what `GetLastError` returns (which might give some clue as to the cause). If you've done neither of those things you should do it now and post the results here (assuming that doing this doesn't help you solve out your own problem).

Comment: My `HANDLE` contains a good handle (not `NULL`) and I've tried `GetLastError` and I get the return 0.

Comment: @Emile Does it work if you load the images from a resource? Sorry I have no idea what the problem is, just trying to help you narrow down the issue. I suspect you might have to debug the MFC code though, to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Change `LR_LOADFROMFILE` to `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION|LR_LOADFROMFILE` for bitmaps

Comment: @BarmakShemirani That's it ! Can you make your comment as the answer of the question ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION|LR_LOADFROMFILE` flag when loading bitmap files for `CMFCButton`

```
::LoadImage(nullptr, bitmapfile, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION|LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

Partial explanation:

MFC source code for `CMFCButton` (`"afxbutton.cpp"`) shows it adds `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION` for `LoadImage`. This is not documented and it is not clear why it needs that. It seems `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION` is required when source bitmap is not 32-bit.

Comment: MFC probably adds the `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION`, so that it has access to a canonical representation of the image internally. Similar in spirit to keeping all datetimes in UTC: The information is true, regardless of the environment. The "DI" in DIB means "device independent" after all, with the device being the external state DDB's need to be properly interpreted. If you find time, post an issue on the [CMFCButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcbutton-class) documentation page.